# Windows Azure can't start locally

Tags: azure

I've been developing windows azure for a while and it worked fine until this morning.

Today I uninstalled .NET 4.5 preview and asp.net mvc 4 beta. After that I installed asp.net mvc 4 beta again. Then suddenly all my windows azure project can't start.

I got "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied." if my web role was an asp.net mvc project.

"500 - Internal server error." , if the web role was an asp.net web project.

I tried to debug the project, but I got ""there was an error attaching the debugger to the IIS worker process for URL '...' for role instance ....

It works correctly if the project is just a single asp.net mvc project or asp.net web project.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this today after uninstalling .net 4.5...you need to re-register ASP.NET 4.0 with IIS 7.x. aspnet_regiis -i

Comment: Thanks Bart, but this didn't work for me. I got a  "Failure Changing IIS ApplicationHost.config" error after I ran aspnet_regiis -i. I've also tried the solution in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougste/archive/2010/09/06/errors-installing-asp-net-4-0.aspx), no luck. So in the end, I had to reinstall iis 7, now it is working as usual.

Comment: I ran into the problem after installing IIS on a computer that previously only had IIS Express. This answer solved the problem for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Bart, but this didn't work for me. I got a "Failure Changing IIS ApplicationHost.config" error after I ran aspnet_regiis -i. I've also tried the solution in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dougste/archive/2010/09/06/errors-installing-asp-net-4-0.aspx), no luck. So in the end, I had to reinstall iis 7, now it is working as usual.

Comment: I just had to manually set the windir path to c:\windows (as the post link says) and run aspnet_regiis and everything worked on two of my machines.  Maybe your IIS was misconfigured as well (?)  Problem with ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta is the designer locks up, crashes or is really slow...lots of people are reporting this.